# How do I customize a Vaadin Grid which contains Jooq Records?

Tags: java, vaadin, jooq

I need to add/remove/customize columns from a Vaadin Grid which contains auto generated jooq records.

```
BeanItemContainer<MyJooqRecord> beanItemContainer;
beanItemContainer = DBUtil.getAll();
Grid grid = new Grid();
grid.setContainerDataSource(beanItemContainer);
```

now I like to (for example) add a Button.

```
grid.addColumn("Action", Button.class).setRenderer(
            new ButtonRenderer(new RendererClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void click(RendererClickEvent event) {
                   //code ...
                }
            }
    ));
```

result:

```
2016-11-30 10:39:17,950 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] [DirectJDKLog.java:181] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Container for this Grid is not a default container from Grid() constructor] with root cause
```

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Container for this Grid is not a default container from Grid() constructor

with Vaadin Tables it just works fine. But after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30134479/vaadin-grid-vs-table) I like to use Grids

The reason why this happens I found [here](https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/9601633/9601649)

How to write a Container with simple Beans I found [here](https://vaadin.com/wiki?p_p_id=36&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=row-1&p_p_col_pos=2&p_p_col_count=4&_36_struts_action=%2Fwiki%2Fview&p_r_p_185834411_nodeName=vaadin.com+wiki&p_r_p_185834411_title=Using+Grid+with+a+Container)

How can I achieve that with jooq records?

any advice please

---

Java 1.7 - Vaadin 7.7.3

Answer (score 0):

change

```
grid.setContainerDataSource(beanItemContainer);
```

to

```
//grid.setContainerDataSource(beanItemContainer);
GeneratedPropertyContainer wrapperContainer = new GeneratedPropertyContainer(beanItemContainer);
grid.setContainerDataSource(wrapperContainer);
```

to `REMOVE` a column

```
wrapperContainer.removeContainerProperty("createdDate");
```

to `ADD` a column

```
wrapperContainer.addGeneratedProperty("Col. Name", new PropertyValueGenerator<String>() {

        @Override
        public String getValue(Item item, Object itemId, Object propertyId) {

            return "Button Caption";

        }

        @Override
        public Class<String> getType() {

            return String.class;

        }
});
```

to `CUSTOMIZE` a column (add a renderer) like this

```
grid.getColumn("Col. Name").setRenderer(new ButtonRenderer(new RendererClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void click(RendererClickEvent event) {

            MyJooqRecord record = (MyJooqRecord) event.getItemId();
            //code ...
        }
}));
```

Comment: found [another source](http://demo.vaadin.com/book-examples-vaadin7/book/#component.grid.renderer.button) with Java 8 examples